# Catch the 'Post to Facebook' event of the Like button

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments, social-media

I have implemented the Facebook 'Like Button' by using 
    fb:like

and I successfully managed to implement logic for the 'Like' event by using

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
//do something
});
```

and now when the user clicks the Like button a bubble box appears with a text box with default text 'Add a comment' and two buttons - 'Post to Facebook' and 'Close'.

I want to catch the event that is triggered by clicking the 'Post to Facebook' button.

I tried to use the following:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
//do something
});
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Can you tell me if there's another event that I should listen to or is this 'comment.create' the right one and I'm just not implementing it correctly?

Thanks